# MariaDB joining tables on themselfs

Tags: sql, mariadb

Ok, I've googled, i've tried but mostly i failed.

I've got a table with 5 columns
ID (just a primary key)
UserUUID
Category
Value

I can pull a query where i get the rankings of a specific category for all users

```
SELECT 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.cat ORDER BY value DESC) as rank,
t1.UUID, t1.cat, t1.value  
FROM t1
WHERE t1.cat='Category1'
ORDER by t1.value DESC
```

So this outputs something like:

```
| 1 | sdc9c4-541 | cat1 | 16102 |
| 2 | sqdf5d-542 | cat1 |  7313 |
| 3 | sqsd5d-685 | cat1 |  7116 |
| 4 | s45sdf-213 | cat1 |  4158 |
.....
```

This works, but now i'm trying to get the reverse view on this.
So I'm trying to pull a query where i get the rankings of a user category for all categories
The desired output should look something like:

```
|  1 | sdc9c4-541 | cat1 | 16102 |
| 37 | sdc9c4-541 | cat2 |    25 |
| 15 | sdc9c4-541 | cat3 |  2345 |
|  2 | sdc9c4-541 | cat4 |   912 |
```

This showing the Rank, User, Category and value's. where the rank represents the users ranking on that category in comparison with other users

I've already messed around with subqueries, with clauses, variables, joins. but i can't get this result to come out and work.

Is there anybody that can give me some pointers in what direction i need to look to make this work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what your ranking algorithm is for the categories. For example `cat3` has a higher `value` than `cat4` but is ranked significantly below it. Please [edit] your question and add sample data, expected output and the reasons for the expected output.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The idea is to Show the users ranking on that category in comparison with other users in that same category.

Comment: What determines the ranking of a user in a category? When there are i.e. two users in one category, how can we know which users get rank=1 and which user gets rank=2 ?

Comment: It's something like this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=fcb24b8b75cb341a4fa61716016e385c) but not enough info is give to help you 

Comment: The ranking is decided on the value, so the users with the highest value on a cat should receive rank 1 for that cat

Comment: `
SELECT @ref:=t1.cat as cat, t1.value, ranks.rank
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN users ON users.UUID = t1.UUID 
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT 
 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.cat ORDER BY value DESC) as rank,
 t1.UUID, t1.value  
 FROM t1 
 LEFT JOIN users ON users.UUID = t1.UUID 
 WHERE cat=@ref and users.name = 'user1'
 ORDER by value DESC 
) AS ranks ON ranks.UUID =  'user1'
WHERE users.name = user_var_name
ORDER BY ranks.rank DESC 
`

the closest i've got to the desired result was above query, however that only pulls one row in the left join subquery, so it always produces rank 1